# should parent entity always have a primary key?

Tags: database-design

I am have 3 entities, Person(fname, lname) none of them is primary, then User(**email**, password) and Receptionist(**emp_id**) bold is primary key. I have extended there two entities from Person, total *participation* and *overllapping*, so person must be either user or receptionist or both at the same time. Is it okay if I do not use primary key in Person

Comment: If you don't have a primary key in `Person`, how are you planning to uniquely identify persons? I hope you're not thinking that every person on Earth has a unique name.

Comment: Formally it's enough to have UNIQUE key for record (Person) identifying... it's not best practice, of course.

Answer (score 0):

How can you identify each record if you don't have primary key. What if there is person having the same name and use it for future data. You must have primary key for table Person.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it okay if I do not use primary key in Person

No, not really. Consider the scenario where you have John Smith the Receptionist and John Smith the User - how would you tell them apart?

You should have a Person entity that contains as many of the attributes common to the child entities as possible (email, for example, is probably a common attribute) and the Person entity should have a primary key. Your child entities (Receptionist and User) then have their own primary key and a foreign key back to Person, as well as the attribute unique to that entity only (employee id, for example, is a unique attribute for Receptionist rows).